# how to get the number of pair values in array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying this solution but it is not giving me the result I want.
I don't want to count the number of pairs of 1 cause it is not really a pair as it appears 4 times.
I need to count the "perfect" pairs, like in this case: 5 and 2. Right now this is giving me 4 as result and it should be 2.

How could I achieve that? I am stuck.

```js
let ar1 = [12, 5, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2];

const countPairs = (ar) => {
  let obj = {};

  ar.forEach((item) => {
    obj[item] = obj[item] ? obj[item] + 1 : 1;
  });

  return Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc += Math.floor(curr / 2);
    return acc;
  }, 0);
};

console.log( countPairs(ar1) )
```

Comment: do you understand your own code? your saving all the matches to an object, why dont you just count the values which has 2

Comment: not sure I get you, how would you do it?

Comment: shouldn't `1` be a true pair also?

Comment: look at Sopheak, that pretty much does what I was refering to

Comment: @decpk cause it appears 4 times, I only want perfect pairs, numbers that appear ONLY twice, not more, not less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the object values by 2 and count the list

```js
let ar1 = [12, 5, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2];

const countPairs = (ar) => {
  let obj = {};

  ar.forEach((item) => {
    obj[item] = obj[item] ? obj[item] + 1 : 1;
  });
  
  return Object.values(obj).filter(e => e == 2).length;
};

console.log(countPairs(ar1))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be one-liner using [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as:

```
const countPairs(arr)  => [...arr.reduce((dict, n) => dict.set(n, (dict.get(n) ?? 0) + 1), new Map()).values(),].filter((n) => n === 2).length;
```

```js
let ar1 = [12, 5, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2];

const countPairs = (arr) =>
  [
    ...arr
      .reduce((dict, n) => dict.set(n, (dict.get(n) ?? 0) + 1), new Map())
      .values(),
  ].filter((n) => n === 2).length;

console.log(countPairs(ar1));
```

Answer (score 0):

or that

```js
const 
  ar1 = [12, 5, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
, countPerfectPairs = arr => arr.reduce((r,val,i,{[i+1]:next})=>
    {
    if(!r.counts[val])
      { 
      r.counts[val] = arr.filter(x=>x===val).length
      if (r.counts[val]===2) r.pairs++
      }
    return  next ? r : r.pairs
    },{counts:{},pairs:0}) 


console.log( countPerfectPairs(ar1) )
```

If you prefer Details:

```js
const 
  ar1 = [12, 5, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
, countPerfectPairs = arr => arr.reduce((r,val)=>
    {
    if(!r.counts[val])
      { 
      r.counts[val] = arr.filter(x=>x===val).length
      if (r.counts[val]===2) r.pairs++
      }
    return r
    },{counts:{},pairs:0}) 


console.log( countPerfectPairs(ar1) )
```